# Inno Setup: File Association not working

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to associate a filetype with my program with Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u). This somehow does not work: *no program* is associated to my extension and *no icon* in being shown in explorer.

Note that when copying the registry values found in regedit and pasting them into explorer, the icon and the program open, respectively.

Here is my code, nearly identical to the one present in the [Inno FAQ](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc).

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".wcalc"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "BHKW-Calc Datei"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\icon.ico,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""
```

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: And have you set the `[Setup]` section directive `ChangesAssociations` to `yes` as suggested ? You have to do that otherwise the system won't be notified about the Shell changes and those changes will be seen only if some program send this notification or after you re-logon to the system.

Comment: Yes TLama, I have `ChangesAssociations=yes` in `[Setup]`. I even try restarting, but it had no effect.

Comment: P.S. even if you do that, I have noticed on a few systems, that Explorer didn't hear that notification and shown the icons in newly opened windows only after you closed all its currently opened windows. I've noticed that mostly in Windows 7, but a few people reported this on Windows XP as well. But that's the Windows issue and should not affect the program association change (just its visual representation).

Comment: The association is not done: double-clicking on the `.wcalc` file brings the Open With dialog.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on the same version of Inno Setup on Windows 7 64-bit with the most recent updates. Didn't have a program with icon as you used, but the association was assigned and immediately after finishing wizard I was able to open a *.wcalc file with that application. Here's my [`testing script`](http://pastebin.com/q6kuLqJp) which you can run from the Inno Setup's Examples folder.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, TLama. I now understood that my installation script actually works on all machines except one: mine. I've had many previous installations of my program and therefore also many association. The program changed name, etc. Something blocked the process - which key exactly is still unknown to me. Anyway, problem is "solved". Thanks a lot -  once a again - for your quick and efficient help!

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, couldn't this be an antivirus in some very strict mode (which would prevent file association changes) ?

Comment: It is not the antivirus: I tested the program on the machines of colleagues with the same antivirus (and antivirus settings) and it worked. I could force the association though, through setting the default program in the Open With dialog in Explorer. Not elegant, but worked.

Comment: I have the same version 5.5.4 and I have the same problem. By checking what inno does to the registry, I see that my association key is created but nothing is created inside of it to specify the icon and the launch program.

Comment: @v.oddou, that will be a different problem I think. Creating registry key values works fine and is proven. Double check if you're creating those values to correct registry path (optionally ask new question).

Comment: apparently, it does create the necessary stuff I just wasn't looking at the place where they really go. But my explorer wouldnt exhibit the change so I thought they weren't created. It just so happens that explorer wants to keep my old manual association rather than the one that Inno sets in the registry. So I cannot check that Inno works well on this machine. I have to check on a fresh machine. I manually changed the association in the properties and could see the program installed by Inno in the option list, so I guessed it would be working on a fresh machine.